# How to find value with in range

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, genetic-algorithm

I have a table `EmployeeSequence` like below

| id | sequence_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1-4 |
| 3 | 5-9 |
| 4 | 10-19 |
| 5 | 20-29 |
| 6 | 30-39 |
| 7 | 40-49 |
| 8 | 50-99 |
| 9 | 100-149 |
| 10 | 150-199 |
| 11 | 200-249 |
| 12 | 250 or above |

How can find the value's range in my code below. Now when i submit the range (35), i want to find the range it belongs to so i can get the respective sequence_name.

I have some code so please clean-up.

```
function findSequenceInRange($sequence) {
                $employee_sequences = EmployeeSequence::all();
                $employment_range = 0;
                foreach ($employee_sequences as $employee){
                    if($employee->sequence_name > 0 && $employee->sequence_name!='250 or above'){
                        $nums = explode('-',$employee->sequence_name);
                        if($sequence >= $nums[0] && $sequence <= $nums[1]){
                            $employment_range = $employee->sequence_name;
                        }
                    }else if($sequence >= 250){
                        $employment_range = $employee->sequence_name;
                    }else if($sequence==0){
                        $employment_range = $employee->sequence_name;
                    }
                }
                
        return  $employment_range;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [groupby](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) with callback and return the id based on sequence. As there is no overlap in the size of your ranges the best approach might be to just hardcode the if-else structure. A little prettier could be to make an array out of it e.g.

```php
$ranges = [
    [
        'min' => 1
        'max' => 4,
    ],
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the cleaner way would be to change your table as to include a "min" and "max" column. This way, you'll be able to easily get the expected result with an SQL request (giving you the option to use it on your Models too)

If you do so, your request will look something like this and give you the expected result :

"SELECT * FROM sequence_table WHERE $sequence > sequence_table.min AND
$sequence < sequence_table.max"